# Query Strings & Mod ReWrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not too inexperienced with ReWrite (not a master either, though) so I was hoping somone might be able to help me.

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=home [NC]
RewriteRule ^adm$ index.php?page=adm_home [NC]
RewriteRule ^adm/stats index.php?page=adm_stats [NC]
```

Above is a snippet of my .htaccess file. As you can see, when someone visits http://www.example.com/adirectory/ it actually calls on index.php?page=home, similarly if someone goes to http://www.example.com/adirectory/adm/ it will still call index.php?page=adm_home within the "adirectory".

What I'm wanting to achieve is this: I want to be able to display alerts on my pages, and to do this I want to simply be able to add alert=n (where n is a number) and thus have the redirect as index.php?page=home&alert=n

However, I can't understand how this can be done, regex is confusing me. Seeking your help.

Comment: Where do you want to be able to add the “alert=n”?

Comment: Good point, I didn't explain that :)

it would append to the end: http://www.example.com/adirectory/?alert=n or http://www.example.com/adirectory/adm/?alert=n

If that's possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to automatically append the originally requested query string to the new one:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=home [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^adm$ index.php?page=adm_home [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^adm/stats$ index.php?page=adm_stats [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Dangit, I've been parsing the $_SERVER variables to extract this information myself. +1