# Mod Rewrite with Pagination

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I wanna make this rather simple to ask so I can hope for a simple response. I'm somewhat new to mod rewriting (most I've done is a small cms using `index.php?page=x` and mod rewriting to that name). I have a shopping cart created by foreign people for my company before I started working here with little to no documentation and they are asking me to make the cart search engine friendly. I won't get too dirty with the details, just need to ask a question.

I have, say, `results.php?name=friendly-url`. I've edited my `.htaccess` so I can access these pages with a friendly url. It works perfectly.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html$ results.php?name=1
```

Now the cart has it written to paginate kinda awkwardly only because the `$_GET` variable is stupidly named. I'm trying to find out, without having to get really dirty and having to re-name files or re-route directories in the code, to make a simple friendly pagination.

The end result I'm looking for is something like `starter-kits-01.html` and `starter-kits-02.html` and so on. This is the mod rewrite I've been trying just to get something to work.

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z-0-9-]+).html?p=([0-9]+)$ results.php?name=$1&pageNum_rsCWResults=$2
```

That, I believed, should allow me to render `starter-kits.html?p=2`. I'm getting no mod rewrite error, but it's messing up my `$_GET` variables. I can't do, say, `/starter-kits/2/` without getting dirty and having to go through this messy code the foreign people made and change 500 lines of directories.

I've spent about 30 minutes on it, and I have 3 other projects going on today, so I'm going to move onto those while I wait for somebody a little more experienced with mod rewriting to give me a helping hand.

Much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Strings & Mod ReWrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487726/query-strings-mod-rewrite) - Please use the search first and also see the Related section on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html$ results.php?name=1 [QSA]
```

The QSA part tells it to forward any GET parameters on to the rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 0):

The page rewriting you need to do should be done in PHP itself and only require a few lines in mod rewrite. I really recommend you download a copy of Drupal or WordPress to see how they do it. But basically here is how it should work.

You create a URL structure like this:

- product-search/cat-toys
- product-search/cat-toys/page-1 (should point to the same place as the previous URL)
- product-search/cat-toys/page-2 (could also use "product-search/cat-toys/page/2)

You take your site and have everything relay through a central index.php file, mod rewrite takes care of this. You just use the URLs on your site and the PHP will take the params passed and parse it into the URL structure that then takes you to the results.

Essentially the URL path is passed to index.php to one parameter by mod rewrite.

Sample mod rewrite entry (from Drupal, very similar to Wordpress):

```
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please check out these systems to get a better idea. WordPress is a much simpler, more straightforward system to go through.