# mod rewrite with query

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query Strings & Mod ReWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487726/query-strings-mod-rewrite)

I'm attempting to use mod rewrite to make links prettier without www and go from:
`http://example.com/folder/page.html` to 
`http://example.com/index.php?page=page&folder=folder`

I've managed a basic version of this for top layer pages which are not in folders but am puzzeled how to include this rule and get folder to appear. I would also like query strings to stay so piwik analytic links work, such as:
`http://example.com/folder/page.html?piwik=something` goes to:
`http://example.com/index.php?page=page&folder=folder&piwik=something`

Any help would be most appreciated, this is what I've got so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`QSA` flag<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), example code below:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+/)?(.+\.html)$ /index.php?folder=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Reference:
Found this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html
Just hit CTRL+F and search for "QSA" (without speech marks)