# why isnt my mod-rewrite working on my pagination

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query Strings & Mod ReWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487726/query-strings-mod-rewrite)

I have written a .htaccess file which correctly translates the following line into

```
http://localhost/questions/32/new-question-from-peter
```

into

```
http://localhost/questions.php?question_id=32.
```

The code I use is

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/[^/]*(?:\?(.+)=(.*))?$ public/questions.php?question_id=$1&$2=$3 [NC,L]
```

However when the url is the following,

```
http://localhost/questions/32/new-question-from-peter?page= <int>
```

it will not process the page information correctly even though when my url is

```
http://localhost/questions.php?question_id=32&page=2
```

it works perfectly.

Can someone help me with this please, where in my code have I gone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/[^/]*/?$ public/questions.php?question_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The query string (`&page=2`) is handled automatically in this case, so you don't need to deal with it in your regular expression, and is appended to the end of the rewritten URL.

Comment: Thanks so much, saved me loads of time

Comment: when i can :-) i like being accepted too!

Answer (score 1):

A good, general way to debug mod_rewrite is to set up a logfile and check what goes on during rewriting:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
</IfModule>
```